# Using a calendar in Xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, ios5, calendar, xcode4.2

i have xcode 4.2 and i am looking at creating a calendar in a tabbed application but I'm fairly new to Xcode and I'm not to sure what there called someone told me it a `NSCalender` but i really think thats wrong hence its not working very well is there any other methods I'm look at making a app that you can add dates in your calendar from my app hope i have explained this correct hope to hear from you soon thanks very much.

if you want to ask me any question just leave a message and i will be on all day so i will get back to you asap

```
EKEventStore *eventDB = [[[EKEventStore alloc] init] autorelease];
EKEvent *holidayEvent  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventDB];

holidayEvent.title     = [self.item customValueForKey:@"title"];
holidayEvent.startDate = startDate;
holidayEvent.endDate   = endDate;
holidayEvent.allDay = YES;

[holidayEvent setCalendar:[eventDB defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];

NSError *error;

[eventDB saveEvent:holidayEvent span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&error]; 

if (error == noErr)
{
    [self sendDidFinish];
    return NO;
}
else
{
    [self sendDidFailWithError:error];
}
```

does this go in the .h or .m and what do i add in the view controller

Comment: Instead of NSCalendar try [EKCalendar](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/DataManagement/Reference/EKCalendarClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009564) from the [EventKit framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/EventKit/Reference/EventKitFrameworkRef/_index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
EKEventStore *eventDB = [[[EKEventStore alloc] init] autorelease];

EKEvent *holidayEvent  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventDB];

holidayEvent.title     = [self.item customValueForKey:@"title"];
holidayEvent.startDate = startDate;
holidayEvent.endDate   = endDate;
holidayEvent.allDay = YES;

[holidayEvent setCalendar:[eventDB defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];

NSError *error;

[eventDB saveEvent:holidayEvent span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&error]; 

if (error == noErr)
{
    [self sendDidFinish];
    return NO;
}
else
{
    [self sendDidFailWithError:error];
}
```

Comment: You need to add EventKit framework 
and #import <EventKit/EventKit.h>

Comment: You should edit this into your existing answer, not add a new answer.

Comment: thanks man how can i add import and do i put the code in the .h or .m

Comment: h. for declarations public methods etc, you should put code into .m file.

To add eventKit click on project on left panel, then "build phases" -> link binary with libraries, click + and find EventKit framework

Comment: i did the event kit frame thing but what code do i write in the .h

Answer (score 0):

So, you need to import events from your app to native iphone calendar? You should use EventKit... 
You can use https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary calendar for you app

Comment: hi inject iOS how would i use that code and which one is the wright code for me. Can you insert it in your answer so i can copy it or look at it there please buddy

Comment: Your are talking about Tapku calendar, or add events to iphone native calendar?

Comment: add events to iPhone native calendar  :)